Refresh Tablix in an SSRS report when Parameter is selected
I have created a report as below, what I want is, when the parameter is selected in the above dropdown, I need the Data in the Tablix below to be refreshed or loaded. I have set the Query for Dataset and parameter is also set, could somebody please help if there is way to achieve the below requirement.
The Chart should remain the same, just the Data in the Tablix should change.
Thank you so much.


parameters are only read when you click "View Report" or open the report with all parameters specified. You could start with a default value for the parameter and handle that in your dataset query to return all data (if that's what you need) and then if the parameter value is set and "View Report" is clicked, then apply the filter
to the tablix according.
